# JavaFX turn off virtual keyboard for a Textfield or by code at runtime for a while

Tags: java, javafx, keyboard, virtual

I am developing a JavaFX touch screen application amongst other things with scanning some barcodes.
When the Textfield for scanning the barcode has the focus the virtual keyboard is popping up. In this case, I want to deactivate the virtual keyboard for this Textfield or closing the virtual keyboard from code at runtime.
Can I trigger the Key `Hide Keyboard` from code at runtime?
For some other user interaction, I need the virtual keyboard.

Is there any way to handle this?

**Remark:** I have activated the virtual keyboard by setting the VM argument:
`com.sun.javafx.virtualKeyboard=javafx`

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When the textfield is in focus you can detach the virtual keyboard:

```
textFeild.focusedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>()
{
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> arg0, Boolean oldPropertyValue, Boolean newPropertyValue) 
    {
        if (newPropertyValue)
            FXVK.detach();
    }
});
```